# How to debug a new relic agent in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, newrelic

So, after a step-by-step configuration of the New Relic Agent on Azure and the inclusion of its library in my MVC ASP.Net Application I still can´t get any data to be sent/displayed in new relic's website.

Where do I start debugging this installation? Does anyone here have any hints as to what I might have forgotten? Is there a minimum quantity of traffic I need to have on my website in order to have data displayed on my dashboard?

And now... a totally newbie question - how can I access my dashboard?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I followed the steps below to get started with the New Relic Agent on Azure. And I could get the performance data of my Azure Web App on the dashboard of the New Relic website. You could refer to it and try to check with your steps.

1.[Create a New Relic account in Azure Portal](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/create-new-relic-account-azure-portal)

2.Follow this [tutorial](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-portal) to install the New Relic's agent for .NET with Portal Azure Web Apps. Also, if your application runs on Azure Classic Portal, you could follow this [tutorial](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-installation/azure-classic-portal-web-apps) to install New Relic's .NET agent.

**Note:** Your app need to receive traffic before you could view the performance in New Relic. And it would take a few minutes for data to appear in the dashboard.

In order to check your app's performance, you could click the `Visit New Relic` from the top of your New Relic account blade in new Azure Portal as follows:

[image]

In summary, please make sure that you have correctly added the configuration key values with your web app and disable the `Always On` setting if you are using Azure's Standard or Basic tiers as the official tutorial mentioned. For more details, you could follow [Azure Troubleshooting](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/azure-troubleshooting).

Comment: Thank you Bruce - One key part of debugging my New Relic installation is the Log folder and setting New Relic log to debug levels.

After analyzing the logs I realized that when I created my application, I  also included the Application Insights objects - which kind of prevent New Relic from collecting data. 

In the end - after losing 5 hours between library inclusion and removal and deployments to Azure I gave up. I might give it another try in the future, though. 

Thanks once more!